# SQL - подобное хранение данных в PHP

Tags: php, sql, хранение-данных

Встречали ли вы такой класс в PHP, чтобы хранить в нем данные таким образом, чтобы можно было извлекать их как в SQL запросах?(условия на совпадение, равенство, подобие шаблону. Какой-то такой хитрый вариант, чтобы выполнялись эти запросы быстро)

Все, кто прочитав это, собрались посылать меня в динамическое создание\удаление БД: Этот вариант не подходит.

Comment: Объясните подробнее, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

Я бы вам порекомендовал сменить работодателя, если он ставит такие задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно смотреть в сторону ORM.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял:
Цитата из комментария к верхнему ответу:
может вам вообще не БД нужна, а контейнеры?
Ответ:
Совершенно верно